# Reactjs change variable with diferent file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have 2 files 'main page' and 'menu'

This is menu.js

```
module.exports = class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      username : '',
      password : ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <Text
          style={styles.item}>
          {{ this.state.username  }}
        </Text>


        <Text
          style={styles.item}>
          Logout
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

};
```

and this is the main page (main_page.js)

```
 import Menu from './Menu.js';
  module.exports = class Main extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <View>

          <Menu />
        </View>
      );
    }
  };
```

I want to change variable value in menu.js by triggering some function in main_page.js. How can I do that?

Comment: Rather than `change variable value in menu.js by triggering some function in main_page.js`, just pass the new value in as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to maintain **the state by parent component Main** instead of in Menu, and pass the value and a function from Main to Menu component. Call that passed function from Menu and pass the value that you want to change.

Use this to call the change function from Menu:

`this.props.change('abc')`

Write it like this:

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text
                  style={styles.item}>
                  {this.props.username}
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={styles.item}>
                  Logout
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
};

import Menu from './Menu.js';
export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            username : '',
            password : ''
        };
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }

    change(value){
        this.setState({password: value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Menu password={this.state.password} change={this.change}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```